# How to create the input dialog with different input fields and get the input fieild value in single activity by extending DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

after searching many docs i am able to use DatePicker,TimePicker in the same activity but not found any information how to use different custom input dialog by extending DialogFragment with different input fields and get the input in activity .

Please provide me some hints to solve this.

Comment: define custom please :)

Comment: means customized input Dialogs